# How to connect SSH tunnel tcp/udp in android

Tags: java, android, ssh, tcp, udp

how can I connect SSH Tunnel TCP/UDP in android using java language, I tried with JSCH but it doesn't work, is there any other way to connect

Comment: Your *question* is complete unclear and missing all relevant information

Answer (score 1):

As @jeb said your question is unclear, but if you are trying to make an ssh connection in android using java you can use this :

First of all you have to add the internet permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Then use this following code in Thread/Executor or Async class (in this case im using Thread) :

```
final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // create a connection instance and connect to it
                Connection ssh = new Connection(hostname);

                ssh.connect();
                final boolean authorized = ssh.authenticateWithPassword(username,
                        password);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (!authorized)
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "could not establish connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "wohoo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });


                // if authorized, create the session
                Session session = ssh.openSession();

                // terminate the session
                session.close();

                // terminate the connection
                ssh.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                //System.exit(2);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: many thanks, where can i get the Connection library?

Comment: you're welcome, im using ch.ethz.ssh2.Connection, ch.ethz.ssh2.Session in this example